# JPA Mapping Error -not provided sufficient metadata in your id class

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I am trying to do mapping in JPA.

```
@Entity
public class Auction {

    @Id
    private Integer auctionId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="auctionId")
    @MapKey(name="auctionParamId")
    private Map<AuctionParam, AuctionParamValue> values;

}

@Entity
public class AuctionParam {

    @Id
    private Integer auctionParamId;

    private String description;

}

@Entity
public class AuctionParamValue {

    @EmbeddedId
    private AuctionParamValuePK pk;

    private String value;

}

@Embeddable
public class AuctionParamValuePK {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="auctionId")
    private Auction auction;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="auctionParamId")
    private AuctionParam auctionParam;

}
```

Showing an error:-

> .Error-Details:-Exception Description:
>   Entity [class
>   com.eaportal.domain.AuctionParamValue]
>   uses [class
>   com.eaportal.domain.AuctionParamValuePK]
>   as embedded id class
>   whose access-type
>   has been determined as [FIELD].
>   But
>   [class
>   com.eaportal.domain.AuctionParamValuePK]
>   does not define any [FIELD]. It is
>   likely that you have not provided
>   sufficient metadata in your id class
>   [class
>   com.eaportal.domain.AuctionParamValuePK].

If you come up with a solution please let me know.

Thanks in Advance
Tushar

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an EmbeddedId with relationships.  Use an IdClass.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(AuctionParamValuePK.class)
public class AuctionParamValue {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="auctionId")
    private Auction auction;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="auctionParamId")
    private AuctionParam auctionParam;

    @Basic
    private String value;

}

public class AuctionParamValuePK {

    private int auction;
    private int auctionParam;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some errors in your `Auction` class. This is how I think it should look

```
@Entity
public class Auction {

    @Id
    private Integer auctionId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="auction") // not auctionId
    @MapKey(name="auctionParam") // not auctionParamId
    private Map<AuctionParam, AuctionParamValue> values;

}
```

(The annotation values have to correspond with fields (or properties), not with columns)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I made the correction but still getting the same error, any other pointer ?

Comment: Im facing this problem now. Has anyone got a clue on the answer?